# Frida crashing when not in console

Tags: javascript, android, frida

I am getting this error when trying to **print all classes** or for that matter any **js** I'm trying to load.

The script is taken from [here](https://github.com/antojoseph/frida-android-hooks), it has quite some useful hooks.

The js part is --

```
setTimeout(function() {
    Java.enumerateLoadedClasses({
        onMatch: function(className) {
            send(className);
        },
        onComplete: function() {
            send("done");
        }
    });
}, 0);
```

I'm very new to frida.

```
Error: VM::GetEnv failed: -2
    at e (frida/node_modules/frida-java/lib/result.js:6)
    at frida/node_modules/frida-java/lib/vm.js:71
    at p (frida/node_modules/frida-java/index.js:171)
    at frida/node_modules/frida-java/index.js:112
    at repl1.js:15
```

Frida version -- **frida-server-10.6.54-android-arm64**  the latest version

### Update

I realised that this happens only when a js file is loaded but doesn't happen if the same js is pasted on console.

It's the same on any app.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this e.g. enum_classes.js:

```
Java.perform(
  function(){
    Java.enumerateLoadedClasses(
      {"onMatch":function(className){
         console.log(className) },
         "onComplete":function(){}
       }
     )
   }
 )
```

And load this js with Frida on the following way:

```
frida -U -l enum_classes.js --no-pause -f <package-name>
```

Run this script on the same directory where you put enum_classes.js or add path before that (e.g. /path/where/you/store/this/frida/script/enum_classes.js)

You can get the package name:

```
frida-ps -U
```